# Relations between 'knee' and 'generation'

Tags: etymology

Recently, a question was asked about the possibility of the words *knee* and *generation* being cognates. Unfortunately, that question is rather unclear, so I'm asking this as a separate post.

The words in question are commonly derived from the PIE words **ǵónu* 'knee' and **ǵenh₁-* 'to give birth, to beget', respectively. The obvious similarity between these two reconstructed forms would be easy to dismiss as a chance resemblance, especially given the lack of an obvious semantic connection. However, it reminded me of a curious parallel in Basque: *belaun* 'knee' and *belaunaldi* 'generation' (with *-aldi* meaning 'period').

It seems someone else has also noticed this interesting parallel (though their other blog posts look a bit dubious at first glance):
https://oldeuropeanculture.blogspot.com/2015/11/from-knee-to-knee.html
They also point out Finnish *sukupolvi* 'generation' from *suku* 'kin' + *polvi* 'knee'.

So there seems to be a connection between the concepts 'knee' and 'generation' in at least three unrelated language families. Has this been treated before in the scientific literature? Is there an obvious connection that I'm just missing (maybe via joint/changing directions/changing generations)? Is it based on a specific concept common to the prehistoric cultures of Europe that's since been forgotten? Or is the parallel formation based on calquing?

Comment: Hmm, that reminds me of a Korean word 슬하 _seulha_ (膝下 - from two Chinese characters "knee" + "under") which means status of being someone's child or descendant. I think its' borrowed from Classical Chinese.

Comment: Interesting. Russian "колено" is indeed used for "generation", albeit this usage feels a bit bookish/archaic. However, only after having read the linked article I realised that the standard modern Russian term "поколение" has the same root, I just never happened to think about this :) Back to "колено" for "generation"  - one of the ideomatics is "колена Израилевы", "The Tribes of Israel", שבטי ישראל (taken from Wiki) from the Old Testament.  Could anyone with the Hebrew knowledge tell if there is a link with a "knee" here?

Comment: @tum_ Hebrew שֵׁבֶט 'tribe' also has the meaning 'staff, rod' but doesn't seem to be related to 'knee'.

Comment: @tum_ Nothing with שבט *shivtei* to my knowledge. Standard BH for "generation" is [תולדה](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/8435.htm) *toldah*, from [ילד](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/3205.htm) *yalad* "to bear (a child)". Also, I thought of בן *ben* "son" and בין *beyn* "between", giving new life to the metaphor, but no, the latter is from a different verbal root ["to discern"](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/995.htm). For knees, there's a link between [ברך](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/1290.htm) *berekh* "knee" and [ברך](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/1288.htm) *barakh* "to kneel, to bless"...

Comment: @tum_ Descendants are יֹצְאֵי יֶרֶךְ "those who come out of the thigh" (Exodus 1:5)

Comment: @ba 'come out of the thigh' hmm. I unfortunately don't read Hebrew at all and fairly weak on Old Testament, especially in English. Yet for some reason the Russian Bible translation tradition (based on Old Church Slavonic which IIRC was based on the Greek Septuaginta) uses this "12 колен Израилевых" set phrase for [ ивр. ‏שִׁבְטֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל‏‎ шивтей Исраэ́ль, арам. שִׁבְטָיָא דֵיִשְׂרָאֵל шивтая дэ-Исраэ́ль] - rus.Wiki. Where the English wiki gives me 'tribes' (I assume that's what the English Bible uses). "Tribe, tribes' are normally expressed in Russian as "племя, племена", so the choice..

Comment: ..of "колено" is intriguing - is there anyone here who can comment on the Greek Bible?

Comment: well, basically, that's where I expect to see γένος as the quoted article suggests.

Comment: απο **φυλησ** 
επι **φυλην** οτι εκαστοσ εν τη κληρονοµια τησ φυλησ τησ πατριασ.. (Numbers 36:7) The **bold** is translated to Russian as "из колена в колено", meaning "from generation to generation". So, not genus, it seems...

Comment: *ankle* vs Ger. *Enkel* (child's child). Thus cp. "Anhang" (fellows, appendage), Lt. *family*; *Spross* (child, shoot), *Sprosse* (step of a latter), *Schößling* likewise, and *Schoß* (lap); Also *shoots and ladders*, *schütten* (to pour), analogously *gießen*, *Erguss*, further Lat. *ergo*, Ger. *ergehen* (ca. understood as *to come down, to follow*, formulaic "Im Namen des Volkes ergeht folgendes Urteil"). Comparing the Veda's cosmogeny springing from 5 body parts, the question might benefit from comparative mythology, which would be out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have anything to say about this particular correlation. However, it is not uncommon to find that there are many PIE "roots" that seem to be sprung themselves from a common "taproot" with semantic coherence.

I [once ran across this](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf) in the set of [English simplex words beginning with *st-](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/st.pdf), which includes

- *stave stab stiff stub stitch stem stand stair step still steep stool*

These (and others) mostly sort out into `Leg/Walk` or `One-Dimensional Vertical`, semantically. This suggests that they might come from some PIE root.
In fact, most do, but they don't come from the same one. 
There turn out to be a **LOT** of PIE roots with this particular meaning, viz (the example words are English cognates):

- *stā- ‘To stand, with derivatives meaning “place or thing that is standing”’ (Pok sta- 1004):
  *style, stand, steed, stud, stay, stage, stamen, stem, station, static, stable, stoic, store, steer*
- *steigh- ‘To stride, step, rise’ (Pok steigh- 1017): *stile, stirrup, stickle, distich, acrostic*
- *steu- ‘To push, stick, knock, beat’ (Pok 2. steu- 1025)
  *stub, stoop, stutter, stock, stoke, steep*
- *stel- ‘To put, stand; with derivatives referring to a standing object or place’ (Pok 3. stel- 1019):
  *stolon, stalk, stele, stilt, pedestal, stolid, stall, stout*
- *ster- ‘Stiff’ (Pok 5. ster- 1029):
  *stare, starch, stork, starve, stark, stern, strut, start, stark, startle*
- *stebh- ‘Post, stem; to support, place firmly on, fasten’ (Pok steb(h)- 1011):
  *stoop, staff, staple, stump, stamp, stomp, stave*
- *steip- ‘To stick, compress’ (Pok steib(h)- 1015)
  *stubble, stiff, stipple*
- *steg- ‘Pole, stick’ (Pok 2. (s)teg- 1014)
  *stake, stack, stagger*
- *stegh- ‘To stick, prick; pointed’ (Pok stegh- 1014)
  *stair, stick, sting, stigma, stimulate, stag*

All this means, of course, is that PIE had predecessors and dialects, which is hardly a surprise. It's just that that's as far back as the comparative method can go.

Comment: ...but there doesn't seem to be any "semantic coherence" in this case.

Comment: This is English. Nothing to do with Hebrew or Spanish. And I was not commenting on _knee_, as I said.